# Continous colors for choropleth in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, colors, leaflet

In Leaflet choropleth to assign colors  you can use this function. http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html

```
function getColor(d) {
return d > 1000 ? '#800026' :
       d > 500  ? '#BD0026' :
       d > 200  ? '#E31A1C' :
       d > 100  ? '#FC4E2A' :
       d > 50   ? '#FD8D3C' :
       d > 20   ? '#FEB24C' :
       d > 10   ? '#FED976' :
                  '#FFEDA0';
 }
```

Instead of a particular breaks in colors is there a way I can just provide the minimum and maximum value and let the colors define themselves?

I have a couple of scales and defining a discrete scale for each of them is not possible.

Any suggestions to use  Chroma.JS https://github.com/gka/chroma.js ?

Comment: What do you mean by "let the colors *[sic]* define themselves"? You don't want to specify any hex codes at all?

Comment: I just want that the breakpoints in colors depends on data and I dont have to specify the breakpoints.   Right now the function has discrete colors. Is there a way to make it continuous for different ranges?

Comment: So you mean that the range might go from 2000 - 5000 for example, and you still want 8 different colours? But don't you need to specify the exact ranges anyway as you will be defining the legend/key

Comment: Yes the ranges are different for different metrics. My main aim is to prevent the bad coloring by an outlier. 
I am not specifying a legend as I only say the darker the shade of the color,  worse the value metric is.  The values are confidential therefore I am not dispalying it

Answer (score 2):

I had same question and while other answer gave some hints I still had to do bit of digging to make it work.

With same Leaflet `getColor` function:

```
function getColor(d) {
return d > 1000 ? '#800026' :
       d > 500  ? '#BD0026' :
       d > 200  ? '#E31A1C' :
       d > 100  ? '#FC4E2A' :
       d > 50   ? '#FD8D3C' :
       d > 20   ? '#FEB24C' :
       d > 10   ? '#FED976' :
                  '#FFEDA0';
 }
```

Using `Chroma.js` it becomes:

```
function getColor(d) {
    var mapScale = chroma.scale(['#FFEDA0', '#800026'])
      .classes([0,10,20,50,100,200,500,1000]);
    return mapScale(d)
}
```

Leaflet legend using this `getColor` function will also populate with same colors as does map. Note that this will return only 4 colors for 5 `classes` values. See docn https://gka.github.io/chroma.js/#scale-classes

Answer (score 1):

> Any suggestions to use Chroma.JS https://github.com/gka/chroma.js ?

Yes, you would use chroma.js. The [usage documentation for chroma](https://github.com/gka/chroma.js#usage) has examples of defining and using a color scale.

The example is:

```
chroma.scale(['lightyellow', 'navy']).domain([1, 100000], 7, 'log');
```

Your code is

```
function getColor(d) {
return d > 1000 ? '#800026' :
       d > 500  ? '#BD0026' :
       d > 200  ? '#E31A1C' :
       d > 100  ? '#FC4E2A' :
       d > 50   ? '#FD8D3C' :
       d > 20   ? '#FEB24C' :
       d > 10   ? '#FED976' :
                  '#FFEDA0';
 }
```

So your thought process is "the scale ranges from 1 to 100000 and changes colors from lightyellow to navy. What does my code do? You look at your code and see that it ranges from FFEDA0 to 800026 on a range from 0 to 1000 (or above 1000).

So you replace the numbers and colors:

```
chroma.scale(['#FFEDA0', '#800026']).domain([0, 1000]);
```

And then use it: add a `var getColor =` so you save this scale as your scale function.

Comment: Any suggestions on how can I use it ?  I have already posted my current function to get color in my question. But i am unable to convert to chroma

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working solution:

```js
function getColor(d, min = 0, max = 100, startColor = '#ffeda0', endColor = '#800026') {
    const scale = chroma.scale([startColor, endColor]).domain([min, max]);
    return scale(d).hex();
}

console.log(getColor(0));
console.log(getColor(50));
console.log(getColor(100));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chroma-js/2.1.0/chroma.min.js"></script>
```

Var names are pretty relevant: `min` and `max` are the ends of the scale, while `startColor` and `endColor` are the corresponding colors.